# First Re may not be empty

Tags: regex, sed

I have written a small piece of code, which it take regex expression from variable and put into sed. When I run the script I get something like this.

```
sed: first RE may not be empty
```

The script delete lines according to specifications from a variable. variable could be empty.

```
NR=$1

sed '/'"${NR}"'/d' in.txt > out.txt
```

How can I fix it or is it some better function which I can use it? :)

Comment: What should it do if `$1` and consequently `NR` is empty? Not delete anything? Delete everything?

Comment: just skip sed - not dele anything. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
# re is set to $1 or $^ if $1 is not provided
re="${1:-\$^}"

# $^ being an invalid regex will NOT delete anything 
sed "/$re/d" in.txt > out.txt
```

Comment: is it possible just set an empty variable? :)

Comment: `sed` won't accept an empty value in regex and what is your rationale of doing it?